# In Xamarin, Is it possible link to a .NET 4.0 assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, xamarin, sqlite-net

I don't have Xamarin yet, and i want to build some application both for android and windows, each will use same shared library.

Is there a possibility to link .NET 4.0 assembly to Xamarin ios/android project, without recompile?
This assembly reference to **System** only, uses **SQLite-NET** by praeclarum, which requires native Windows library **sqlite3.dll**.

As i heard, on Mono/Xamarin? Mono.Data.Sqlite is required instead sqlite3.dll, but i am not sure, can i keep my library "cross-platform" with it? Or i will have to change something?

Unfortunately, i cannot check this currently.
Thank you..

Comment: Why cannot you check this?  There's a free version that limits the size of your application, but it should be more than sufficient for answering questions such as this.  In principle you can write PCLs that are cross-platform, but I'm not sure how this plays with the built-in sqlite stuff provided by Mono.

Comment: The title of your question does not match the contents. SQLite-NET of course is OK, as it is just a few C# source files, but sqlite3 is a native dependency. I believe that Android has already shipped with sqlite3 native library (an .so file), so all you need is there already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.net assemblies can't be linked to Xamarin Android/iOS but you can link PCLs or you can create a Xamarin Android/iOS project, link files from your .net assemblies there and resolve possible problems with conditional directives (#if...).